# Tailwind twin macro with react-select styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-select, tailwind-css

I am using react-select with styled component and it is working but I want to use tailwind classes using twin macro.

```
import tw from 'twin.macro';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Select from 'react-select';
export const StyledReactSelect = styled(Select)(() => [
  `
  .Select__control {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    border-radius: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .Select__control:hover {
    border-color: #a1a1a1;
  }
  .Select__control--is-focused {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
    outline: none;
  }
  .Select__indicator-separator {
    display: none;
  }
  .Select__menu {
    color: #3c3d3e;
  }
`,
]);
```

**Now I want to use tw(twin-macro) with classes of react-select. can anyone help?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering tailwind, tw and styled components are properly set up. We can do something like this:

```
import tw from 'twin.macro';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Select from 'react-select';
export const StyledReactSelect = styled(Select)(() => [
  `
  .Select__indicator-separator {
    ${tw`hidden`}
  }
  .Select__menu {
    ${tw`text-blue-600`}
  }
`,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

since we have intigrated tailwind we can use them like below

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import tw from 'twin.macro';

export const FooterStyled = styled.footer`
  ${tw`flex  bg-gray-800 flex-col`}
`;
```

Comment: Yes this is the way to use twin macro. But here in my case I am styling react-select with styled component and only possible way is to use classes provided by react-select. so I want to apply tailwind classes to react-select classes.

Comment: In a case like this better make your own style wrapper component use in react-select which you can use through the entire application. I will add another answer with a sample code if you need a more specific sample. according to your requirement @Yash Sangai 's answer is correct.